# AJAX call not passing value to action

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View that contains:

```
(...)

<div id="txtMan@(item.ManufacturerId)" hidden>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.ManufacturerName, new { @id = "txtBoxMan"+item.ManufacturerId })
</div>
<td>
    <input class="btnSave" id="btnSave@(item.ManufacturerId)" type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveButtonPressed(@item.ManufacturerId);" hidden />
</td>

(...)
```

The corresponding JavaScript:

```
saveButtonPressed = function (id) {
    var newManName = $('#txtMan' + id).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: '/Admin/BrandConfigurationNameUpdate/' + newManName,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert('Added');
        }
    });
}
```

And the Controller:

```
public static void BrandConfigurationNameUpdate(string id)
{ 

}
```

My objective is to save the textbox value into the database. However, I've put a breakpoint in my Controller and it never reaches it. Any suggestion?

EDIT:
I've tryed with a GetJSON, but still not working. Here's the code:

```
saveButtonPressed = function (id) {
    var newManName = $('#txtBoxMan' + id).val();
    alert(newManName);
    var URL = "~/Areas/Admin/Controller/Admin/BrandConfigurationNameUpdate/";

    $.getJSON(URL, { "id": id, "newManName": newManName }, function (data) {
        alert("finished");
    });
}
```

Comment: does `newManName` show up properly in the `saveButtonPressed` function?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 or 500 error when trying to post?

Comment: did you confirm that newManName  is properly populated?

Comment: No 404 error. And no, I can't confirm that because I have the "No symbols have been loaded for this document” problem. I'm googling how to solve that, but I'm still having issues.

Comment: if you put a debugger; statement above the $.ajax does it break on it in the browser?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But if I put an alert inside the function it does appear. So the JS function is being called properly.

Comment: repeat: did you confirm that newManName is properly populated?

Comment: Yes, newManName is properly populated. I've updated the post. Still not working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a `data` option as an object (key-value pair), or the value won't be POSTed:

```
saveButtonPressed = function (id) {
    var newManName = $('#txtMan' + id).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: '/AdminController/BrandConfigurationNameUpdate/',
        data : {newManName : newManName},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert('Added');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this is better form, and could be the answer (+1 from me). I wonder, though, since I have done ajax calls passing id's by url. always from .load call. Are you sure that he CANT pass the id this way?

Comment: Passing values in the URL is okay, but then it's a GET request, not a POST. If you want values to be POSTed by jQuery, you have to use the `data` option. By the way, that option works with GET too (even with .load), and will conveniently escape/encode the values for you.

Comment: Are you sure that "url: '/AdminController/BrandConfigurationNameUpdate/'" is correct? Shouldn't be Admin without the "Controller" part?

Comment: Ok, now it's working. It works with just "BrandConfigurationNameUpdate". Weird but true.